# Dom manipulation in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

in iOS I need to simulate the navigation taking control of a UIWebView, doing something in the vain of the popular library for Perl / Python / Ruby *mechanize*. Fill and submit forms, follow links, follow redirects and so on, all programmatically.

Is there any solution for the iOS platform? Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but you may not be able to do this with public APIs on iOS. It seems like the kind of thing apple would disallow for security reasons.

Comment: I didn't understand your question - but if you load up a page in a UIWebView then you can inject javascript that manipulates the dom.